# why conventional approximation method is true?

Tags: numerical-methods, proof-writing, approximation-theory, least-squares

why the text book method for finding the fitting curve is right ?

we have n data we want to approximate with a polynomial of degree m $P_m(x)$ (m < n-1).

and of course  $E = \sum_{i=1}^m (y_i-P_m(x_i))^2$

to prove that the error function $E(a_0 , a_1 ,...,a_m)$ is Min where the partial derivatives of E with respect to $a_0 $ and $a_1$ , .. and $a_m$ are $0$; we must first show that this is the only critical point(call it `c`)

( if it's not the only critical point then we need to show E's value is Min in `c` when compared to other critical points ).

then we need to show that E's value in the boundary points are more than its value in `c`.

since we do not have a boundary (it's $\infty$) so we need to show when the function goes to $\infty$ in any direction the values of E are all more than c.

how can i prove this?
why my textbook (burden) does not prove this?
am i over-complicating the case?

Comment: The partial derivatives of $E$ wrt to all coefficients make a system of $m+1$ **linear** equations for $m+1$ unknwons (the coefficients). Taking this into account should help (I hope).

Comment: I think it would be hard to prove from this way. But you can argue from geometric point of view that the maximum is $\infty$ since the curve could deviate far away from the points, and the local minimum is the global min. Or you can argue that this is a hyper-paraboloid which has a global minimum. Another way is to use the matrix form $Ax=b$, and state that the residue has to be perpendicular to the span of $Ax$ to be minimized. I can write that argument if you are interested.

Comment: @ Claude Leibovici i think just because we have m+1 equations and m+1 unknowns does not mean we have a unique answer or an answer at all !

Comment: @ KittyL i think proving the function is a hyper-paraboloid is hard but I'm interested in the matrix technique . although i do not know about it . so please dumm in down. i just wanted to use multivariable calculus technique .

Answer (score 2):

$E$ is a coercive function, so has a global minimum (http://www.math.usm.edu/lambers/mat419/lecture4.pdf). The global minimum is a local minimum, so also a critical point. The only critical point is the global minimum.